# Confused about the use of ... in lua/corona

Tags: syntax, lua, coronasdk

I was researching push notifications for corona and came across this page

https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/notification/type.html

the code I'm confused about is the part at the top

```
-- The launch arguments provide a notification event if this app was started when the user tapped on a notification
local launchArgs = ...
```

what does the `...` mean?

Comment: The two questions are not related, why not split it into two questions?

Comment: because they are trivial questions and dont really need to be split up

Comment: If they are related to each other, sure. However, the two questions here are not related at all.

Comment: theyre both related to confusing syntax on push notification documentation.  do you know the answer to my question?

Comment: I removed the second question. If you would ask it in another question, I could answer it as well. Note that the answer of that question is relatively easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

`...` is the syntax for vararg expressions, which is used in vararg functions.

In this example, `...` is used in the main body of a script. The script can be treated as a vararg function, so `...` here is the arguments of the script.

Comment: implementing my own vararg function i get a table with keys of 1,2,3 etc.  in corona launchArgs ends up being a table with keys like "notification" etc.  how is that possible?

Comment: @hamobi: That depends on what arguments were passed. A varargs expression doesn't control what values you get; it simply allows you to pass multiple arguments and unpack them as you see fit.